# How to calculate a time difference between 2 external interrupts

Tags: stm32, programming

I'm using the STM32CubeIDE, and I want to use the maximum frequency of the chip (100 MHz) to calculate the time between two GPIO external interrupts and then compare that time to a reference (reference time = 2.4 ms).

I guess the general idea is:

//gpio 1 interrupt comes
//start timer
//gpio 2 interrupts comes
//if timer > time reference or time reference ends before interrupt comes
//no action needed (gpio output = 1)
//else timer < time reference
//cut out out (gpio output = 0)

This is code I came up with using some manual calculations:

```
    void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN EXTI0_IRQn 0 */

    for ( i=1;i<11540;i++){
            j=i;
        

  /* USER CODE END EXTI0_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_0);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN EXTI0_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END EXTI0_IRQn 1 */
}

/**
  * @brief This function handles EXTI line3 interrupt.
  */
void EXTI3_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN EXTI3_IRQn 0 */
    if (j<11540){
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1, RESET);

        }

  /* USER CODE END EXTI3_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_3);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN EXTI3_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END EXTI3_IRQn 1 */
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

/* USER CODE END 1 */
```

Comment: The timers have a timer capture feature in hardware, which would be far better choise than to use GPIO interrupts to read timer count in software.

Comment: But even if you do it this way, the right way would be to *start a timer* in the first ISR and  stop/read it in the second.

Answer (score 1):

This is an ARM processor and has access to the internal CPU clock counter. You just have to read the counter in the 1st interrupt and in the 2nd read and subtract (unsigned integers) the result. As long as it doesn't overflow, this is the most precise result you can get.

You will have to look up the documentation, but here are parts of code I use for a similar function (ignore the specific purpose):

```
volatile uint32_t PhaseMicrosARM, PhaseMicrosARM0=0; // From internal counter; not really microseconds. 


     FASTRUN void ftm0_isr(void) { // 60 Hz
    ...
        PhaseMicrosARM0 = ARM_DWT_CYCCNT;
```

and in the 2nd ISR:

```
FASTRUN void ftm1_isr(void) { // 1 Hz; 
    Phase = (ARM_DWT_CYCCNT-PhaseMicrosARM0) * 360LL * Target_Hz / F_BUS; // final result is 0..359; intermediate could be 64 bit (48M*360), so LL forces 64 bit
```

More details at https://forum.pjrc.com/threads/69594-micros()-inside-interrupt?p=300943#post300943